# data not present in 1 table but present in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CAST(tMI.MI AS VARCHAR)
FROM   tMI
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tCard
                    ON CAST(tCard.CardNumber AS VARCHAR) = CAST(tMI.MI AS VARCHAR)
       INNER JOIN tMIMS
               ON CAST(tMIMS.tMI_ID AS VARCHAR) = CAST(tMI.ID AS VARCHAR)
WHERE  tMIMSStatus_ID = 0
       AND tMSRevision_ID = 35
       AND tCard.CardNumber IS NULL
       AND tMI.MI IS NOT NULL
```

Hi All,

above is the SQL i am using.

(the cast is because i was getting conversion issues before not sure if i'm using them right)

i am trying to get a list of all entries in tMI.TI where the tCard.Cardnumber is empty.

can anyone help as to where i am going wrong.

Before i join the 'tMIMS' table it seems to run but give incorrect data.

any help would be great.

Comment: Give a length for casts, i.e. `cast(tMIMS.tMI_ID as varchar(50)) `

Comment: just tried and still didn't work :( thanks though

Comment: Add sample data of all the tables. What error you are getting. Without looking at the data it is hard to tell

Comment: The condition cast(tCard.CardNumber as varchar) = cast(tMI.MI as varchar) contradicts to the condition tCard.CardNumber IS NULL AND tMI.MI IS NOT NULL. These conditions can not simultaneously be true.

Comment: @Sergey - But they don't have to be, one of them is a join predicate and one a predicate on the result of the outer join.

Comment: What table is `tMIMSStatus_ID` and `tMSRevision_ID` from? Though actually you should provide a full example with data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Martin Smith - You are right. I did not notice that tCard is LEFT joined.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data, the result you'd like to get for it and the result you're actually getting?

Comment: @MartinSmith the condition is `tCard.CardNumber is null`, which means it won't join anything, in that case, should we use `not exists / not in` instead of join with a clause always return `false`?

Comment: @Alex - I normally use `NOT EXISTS` but `LOJ ... IS NULL` is quite common.